# Why is `filter` acting this way inside of `lapply`

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I'm getting an unexpected result with `filter` inside of `lapply` that I haven't figured out. I'm trying to cut a data frame into a list of data frames based on timestamps--one data frame per unique timestamp.

```
df <- data.frame( x=rep("a", 3), ts=c(1518904061180, 1518904061180, 1518904087257))
out <- lapply( unique(df$ts), function(x, z){  
  filter(z, ts==x) }, z=df)
out
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] x  ts
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>
> [[2]]
> [1] x  ts
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> ```

I have tested some things, but can't see a problem. E.g. these behave as expected:

```
out <- lapply( unique(df$ts), function(x, z){  
  print(x==1518904061180);
  filter(z, ts==1518904061180) }, z=df)
out

a <- 1518904061180
filter(df, ts==a)
```

Comment: For your task, it seems to me that `split(df, f = df$ts)` would work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jazz yeah, it looks like that works, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Still though, it would be nice to know what is up with filter